# Aggregate functions for collections

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate `COUNT DISTINCT` of the `ids` in the following example code, so the result I'm looking for is `3`.

```
CREATE TYPE tab AS TABLE OF NUMBER(9);

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ids.COLUMN_VALUE ) FROM ( -- pseudo-code, obviously not working
  SELECT tab(1,2) AS ids FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT tab(2,3) AS ids FROM dual
);
```

---

Here's a more complex example of what I'm trying to do, might help to understand my problem:

```
WITH master AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 12 AS duration FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 14 AS duration FROM dual
),
detail AS (
  SELECT 1 AS master_id, 1 AS val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS master_id, 2 AS val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS master_id, 2 AS val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS master_id, 3 AS val FROM dual
)
SELECT MEDIAN( duration ), SUM( count_val )
       -- TODO: COUNT DISTINCT
FROM master m
JOIN (
  SELECT master_id, COUNT(*) AS count_val,
         CAST( COLLECT( val ) AS tab ) AS vals
    FROM detail
   GROUP BY master_id
) d ON ( d.master_id = m.id );
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Aggregate the collections and then use the [`CARDINALITY` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions015.htm#SQLRF06305) to get the size of the collection.

Comment: @MT0: Thanks! Guess I was hoping for a built-in version of your function...